# App autopost to Facebook

Tags: facebook

So, I want to build a web app that posts let say funny cat pics to a users Facebook wall.  The user allows the web app to do this via the `publish_actions` command. Yeah, I know this sounds spammy but it isn't.

Now, on Facebook Developer documentation pages it's described as follows:

> "Enables your app to post content, comments and likes to a user's
>   stream and requires extra permissions from a person using your app.

So, to me this sounds that it's possible for an web app to publish content without the need for the user to grant every single update?

But, reading about it in the "Login Best Practices" section I read the following sentence:

> 1. When displaying the Log in with Facebook button, emphasize that
>      your app will not post to Facebook without people's permission

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist

So, my question is – is it or isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the publish_actions permission allows your app to post to the user's wall without having facebook itself ask for permission again.

However, it is good ("best") practice to always make it explicitly clear inside your app that "by clicking here, I will post to your timeline".

Basically, this is Facebook saying that you should handle this asking inside your application, in a way that best fits your application's logic.

Comment: that´s the point. it IS possible, but you should ALWAYS ask the user before posting anything. else your app will (hopefully) get banned pretty fast.